# how to continue installing packages?

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, katoolin

so I was trying to install `apktool` using `katoolin` on Ubuntu 14.04LTS, while the installation was about to finish I accidentally closed the terminal. I already tried

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

then this popped up

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on gconf-service (= 3.2.6-3); however:
  Version of gconf-service on system is 3.2.6-0ubuntu2.
dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gconf2
```

---

```
% apt-cache policy gconf-service gconf2
gconf-service:
    Installed: 3.2.6-0ubuntu2
    Candidate: 3.2.6-3 
    Version table:
   3.2.6-3 0 
        500 http.kali.org/kali sana/main amd64 Packages
   *** 3.2.6-0ubuntu2 0 
        500 ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/main amd64 Packages 
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
gconf2:
    Installed: 3.2.6-3 
    Candidate: 3.2.6-3
    Version table:
   *** 3.2.6-3 0 
        500 http.kali.org/kali sana/main amd64 Packages 
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status 3.2.6-0ubuntu2 0 
        500 ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the outpout of `apt-cache policy gconf-service gconf2`

Comment: gconf-service:
  Installed: 3.2.6-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 3.2.6-3
  Version table:
     3.2.6-3 0
        500 http://http.kali.org/kali/ sana/main amd64 Packages
 *** 3.2.6-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
gconf2:
  Installed: 3.2.6-3
  Candidate: 3.2.6-3
  Version table:
 *** 3.2.6-3 0
        500 http://http.kali.org/kali/ sana/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.2.6-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages

Comment: sorry, i cant edit my post, only have 1 rep

Comment: First try  `sudo apt-get install -f`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first what you can do is, fix the broken dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

The output of `apt-cache policy gconf-service gconf2` says, the needed version `3.2.6-3` of `gconf-service` is a vaild installation candidate. If the previous command has not solved the problem, run

```
sudo apt-get install gconf-service=3.2.6-3
```

**But my suggestion is, remove the Kali repositories from your system and don't play with Kali without knowing what you're doing:**

```
find /etc/apt -type f -name '*.list' -exec sed -i '/sana/d' {} \;
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: this popped up after 

"sudo apt-get install -f"

Comment: (Reading database ... 197804 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gconf-service_3.2.6-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gconf-service (3.2.6-3) over (3.2.6-0ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gconf-service_3.2.6-3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconf/gconfd-2', which is also in package gconf-service-backend 3.2.6-0ubuntu2

Comment: dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gconf-service_3.2.6-3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Dear OP, don't play with Kali without knowing what you're doing. You have the choice, remove the Kali repositories or we can break your system. What's your goal?

Comment: i'm sorry.  i was just trying out kali :( will it help if i remove the kali repositories?

Comment: Removing the Kali repositories, as described in my answer, helps to repair your system.

Comment: Use Kali Linux, if you have more experience with Linux systems and package managers

Comment: already did. thanks for the help. but i still have the error sign on the upper right side of the toolbar

Comment: Give me the output of `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: it's okay now. thank you very much :) one more thing. i cant find the terminal. when i press ctrl+alt+t it shows the "xterm". are they the same?

Comment: xterm is also a terminal, yes. Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-terminal`

Comment: after the update my desktop became blank :( i tried restarting and still it's blank :( what happened?

Comment: As I said. Don't play with Kali. But I can't answer this in the comments. Ask a [new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).

Comment: already did. please help :(